# Show $T(x) := x+sf(x)$ is a bijection with $f$ Lipschitz and $\vert s \vert \lt \frac{1}{L}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function and $L \gt 0$ such that

$\Vert f(x)-f(y)\Vert \leq L \Vert x-y\Vert\ $for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

1. Show that $T(x) := x+sf(x)$ defines a bijection on $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $\vert s \vert \lt \frac{1}{L}$.
2. Prove that there is a constant $\tilde{L} \gt 0$, such that
   $\Vert T^{-1}(x)-T^{-1}(y)\Vert \leq \tilde{L} \Vert x-y \Vert\ $ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

I can prove that $T$ is injective but I am currently struggling with showing that it is also surjective. I don't really now how to approach 2. - I mean I know that the inverse of $T$ exists I thought about using the surjectivity in order to rewrite $x,y$ as $T(\tilde{x}),T(\tilde{y})$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: For the proof of the surjectivity I have tried to show that $F_y(x):=T(x)-y$ is a contraction. Then it would follow that it has a unique fixed point which would give me the surjectivity. But I didn't manage to estimate a lipschitz constant which is smaller than $1$.

Comment: @thehardyreader trying to prove the existence of a unique fixed point is a nice idea, but that's not the right function to consider, because if $F_y(x)$ has a fixed point $x_0$, that would mean that $T(x_0)-y=x_0$, i.e, $T(x_0)=y+x_0$, which doesn't necessarily show surjectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You want to prove that given $y\in\mathbb R^n$, there exists $x\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $T(x)=y$, i.e, $y-sf(x)=x$, i.e, $x$ is a fixed point of $y-sf(x)$. So consider the function $g_y(x)=y-sf(x)$. Prove that $g_y$ is $|s|L$-Lipschitz. Since $(\mathbb R^n,\|\|$) is complete and $|s|L<1$, by the Banach fixed-point theorem, $g_y$ has a unique fixed point. (this also shows that $T$ is also injective).
2. Notice that, as shown in 1., for $x\in\mathbb R^n$, $T^{-1}(x)$ is the unique fixed point of $g_x$. So given $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, let $x_0=T^{-1}(x)$ and $y_0=T^{-1}(y)$. So you know that $x_0=g_x(x_0)$ and $y_0=g_y(y_0)$. So $\|T^{-1}(x)-T^{-1}(y)\|=\|g_x(x_0)-g_y(y_0)\|\cdots$

Comment: Thank you! I have understood the first part, and working on the second:
$...=\Vert x - s f(x_{0}) - y + f(y_0) \Vert \leq \Vert x-y \Vert + \vert s \vert L \Vert x_0 - y_0\Vert = \Vert x-y \Vert + \vert s \vert L \Vert T^{-1}(x) - T^{-1}(y) \Vert $
Subtracting the last term from both sides and dividing by $1-\vert s \vert L$

Comment: @thehardyreader It's a pleasure :) That's right!! Well done!

Comment: @thehardyreader By the way, out of curiosity, is this exercise from a textbook (probably numerical analysis, looking at your tag). If so, what's the name of the book?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know the original source of this exercise - I got this exercise during my numerical analysis course. I don't know if the professor made it up or took it from a textbook. Sorry, that I can't help - I ask him next week, in order to return the favor.

Comment: No problem :) And people don't help expecting a return of favor ;) I would have asked the question even if I wasn't the one who answered yours ;) Good luck !!